# Assistance with creating grid/ball (objects?) in Java

Tags: java, object, graphics, grid, simulation

I'm trying to create a Roomba program with a ball that bounces around the screen that cleans the tiles that it passes over. The program should start with all grey tiles and when the ball passes over them then the tiles turn white. Currently I have the ball that bounces around everywhere and a grid method which creates a 5x5 grid.

I have encountered two problems:

1. I cannot make the grid and the ball appear in the same simulation while running the program, it's either one or the other.
2. I'm having trouble with finding a way to analyze if the ball has passed over certain squares in the grid, perhaps I need to create an object for the grid/ball?

My code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;

public class Roomba {

private static int windowWidth = 200;
private static int windowHeight = 200;

private static double x = 100;
private static double y = 100;
private static double vx = 2;
private static double vy = 4;
private static int radius = 5;

private static boolean inGame = true;

public static void updateLocations() {
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
}

public static void drawGrid() {
    StdDraw.setScale(0, 5);

    int[][] grid = new int[5][5];

    for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = 255;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            StdDraw.square(x, y, 1);
        }
    }

}

public static void updateVelocities() {

    if (y + radius >= windowHeight) {
        vy = -vy;
    } else if (y - radius <= 0) {
        vy = -vy;
    }

    if (x >= 194 || x <= 6) {
        vx = -vx;
    }

}

public static void setBackground() {
    StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.GRAY);
//      drawGrid();
}

public static void drawBall() {
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, radius);
    // StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
    // StdDraw.filledSquare(x + 3, y + 3, 1);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.text(100, 70, "x is: " + x + " y is: " + y);

}

public static void draw() {
    setBackground();
    drawBall();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(800, 800);

    StdDraw.setXscale(0, windowWidth);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, windowHeight);

    while (true) {
        if (inGame) {
            draw();
            updateVelocities();
            updateLocations();
        } else {
            StdDraw.text(100, 100, "Game Over");
        }

        // change to if all tiles have been cleaned
        // if (x + radius > windowWidth || x - radius < 0) {
        // inGame = false;
        // }

        StdDraw.show(20);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the background is being drawn over the ball or vice verse? Try to draw the ball first then the background? Make sure the ball is actually being rendered at the correct size and not as the entire screen. I'm not to familiar with 2D graphics but maybe there is some z fighting?

Comment: Tried playing around with the order with no luck, when trying to draw both of them they appear for the first frame but not the subsequent frames.